# Does uiautomator support multiple threading

Tags: android, python, android-uiautomator

now, I use uiautomator to do test works on Android. We develop the framework to do different tasks based on python and uiautomator. But I have some questions about the multiple threading to call uiautomator at the some time. For example, in the main function I use uiautomator to detect the text like "Browser" on the Android apps menu, and at the same time I use uiautomator to detect the text like "Calculator" based on python threading module, and then I find the problem sometimes "Browser" can be found, and sometimes "Calculator" can be found, but not always.

I'm puzzled about the uiautomator tool, does it support multiple threading?

Answer (score 0):

UiAutomator works on the current UI of the device/emulator. So if you aren't on the correct screen in which you are searching it will not work, so you have to make it synchronous.

Anyway, as far as I know UiAutomator doesn't like multi-threading. I'm not saying it would present errors or completely fail, but it's a really bad option. I'm saying this not from experience but I've read it (don't recall where sorry) related to the usage of Thread.sleep().